# why does Blender render an image in the compositor?

Tags: compositing-nodes

Compositor beginner here:

I have this compositing node tree:

[image]

why does Blender render my second viewlayer, although i don't use it in the compositor?

[image]

My stupid assumption was, that i could render faster (i had the VL2 layer before instead of the image input), if i just use a static picture as background. But looks like Blender doesn't think like i do....umpf

EDIT:

if i disable the render buttons in VL2, it does what i want.

But really i hoped Blender does something like in GN, if nodes are not used, it wouldn't execute it :(

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you haven't loaded it in the Video Sequencer?

Comment: yes i am sure....

Comment: You should not have to disable anything in VL2 if it is not selected in the Render Layers node

Comment: maybe make your file very simple (replace the robot by a cube) and share your file?

Comment: @moonboots Actually this behaviour is quite normal... see my answer.

Comment: Oh OK I missed it

Comment: @moonboots Well, I added a bit more explanations at the end of the answer... or let's say use cases.

Comment: In all my explanations in the answer I forgot to mention, one of the reasons view layers get rendered even though not used in the _Compositor_: this is post-processing. It does not affect what Blender hands over to the render engine to get rendered. It only affects the output if you plug nodes inbetween. You could also disable the _Compositor_ to render a scene. The only thing is, if it is enabled and nothing is plugged into the _Composite_ node (or there is none), then Blender won't render at all and give an error message for not having anything to output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blender renders **all** view layers which have *Use For Rendering* enabled in the *View Layer Properties*:

[image: use for rendering]

This setting can also be keyframed, let's say you have an animation where you want to use a second view layer to *Alpha Over* in the *Compositor* but only for certain frames. Then you can disable it for all other frames where you don't need it.

If you now have let's say 10 view layers and you want to render only one of them, you do not need to disable 9, in this case you can enable *Render Single Layer* and only this view layer will be rendered.

But: you can still use the other 9 layers in the *Compositor*, when they have been rendered before - Blender will used a cached render of those layers.

This can be useful if your 9 layers create a background image which does not change, and the one layer you set to *Render Single Layer* has an animation which you want to lay over the others.

Sidenote: the option *Render Single Layer* stays enabled when switching to a different view layer. This means, always the active view layer will be single-rendered.

More sidenotes: If you have both view layers in the *Compositor* and made changes on only one of them, you don't have to set *Render Single Layer* and press <kbd>F12</kbd> to re-render that one layer where you have made changes when you want to keep the other without re-rendering. In the *Compositor*, you can just click on the *Render* button next to the view layer's name in the *Render Layers* node to re-render that single layer.

Last but not least: When you press <kbd>F12</kbd> to render a scene and both view layers get rendered even though you have only one in a *Render Layers* node in the *Compositor*, you can add another *Render Layers* node and switch it to the second view layer and it will be used for compositing without having to render again because it had been rendered before.